# Search for segment similarity inside strokes

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision, content-based-retrieval

i am looking for a technique or a known method to search a part of similar segments in a handwritten text.

its a kind of image retrieval, but rather than searching for an entire word or character, i want to search similar parts of strokes given a pattern as input image.

the figure below illustrate this process, where the red segments are input images and red rectangles represent part of text similar to the input.

[image]

by "similar", i mean "approximately", not exact matching

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Shape Context](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/BMP-shape.pdf) can be helpful for your task. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_context).
Shape context descriptor allows you to robustly describe a **local** shape. Finding two shape-context descriptors that are nearly identical strongly suggests that the underlying text pattern are quite similar.

You can find Matlab implementation in the [project's home page](https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/sc_digits.html).

Comment: i suppose that this feature can be done on isolated shapes, but in my case, this patterns are inside shapes, perhaps i will need a segmentation step. i suppose also that this method is sensitive to the size of shapes, but i will give it a try. Thank you @Shai